# criar variavel com @for no scss

Tags: sass, scss, variáveis

bom dia a todos!!
galera eu preciso criar variáveis de cores no SCSS e estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
 @for $i from 1 to 50{
  $corClara{$i}:red;
}
```

mas não to conseguindo fazer funcionar...o koala, na hora de compilar, sempre fala que o problema é no {$i}...tem como concatenar???? o que pode ser feito para criar as variáveis???
obrigado a todos!!
Horácio

Answer (score -1):

Uma sugestão seria, em vez de gerar os nomes das variáveis usando a interpolação, podias criar uma lista e usar o método `nth` para obter os valores.

Exemplo de código:

```
$cor1: rgb(255,255,255); // branco
$cor2: rgb(255,0,0); // vermelho
$cor3: rgb(255,255,0);   // amarelo

$cores: $cor1, $cor2, $cor3;

@for $i from 1 through length($cores) {
        background-color: rgba(nth($cores, $i), 0.6);
}
```

Uma outra abordagem, seria utilizar o `@each` em vez do `@for`, porque assim não precisas saber o tamanho da lista nem utilizar a função `length()` para calcular o tamanho da lista, assim como a função `nth()`.

Exemplo de código:

```
$cores: rgb(255,255,255), // branco
        rgb(255,0,0),     // vermelho
        rgb(255,255,0);   // amarelo

@each $cor in $cores {
        background-color: rgba($cor, 0.6);
}
```